# What's another programmatic method to remove attachment(s) on a Access Form's Attachment Control?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, attachment, multivalue

My Access form has an attachment control, and I want to give the users the ability to overwrite one of a record's files with another copy from their drive.

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rstMain As DAO.Recordset, rstAttach As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fldAttach As DAO.Field2

' *Snip*

Set rstAttach = rstMain(strAttachFielD).Value

rstAttach.AddNew
Set fldAttach = rstAttach.Fields("FileData")

   '----------------------------------------------
   '  Here goes "blnFileExists" code that determines whether 
   '  "Myfile.txt" is already in the attachment
   '----------------------------------------------

   If blnFileExists Then
       ' *** Delete "MyFile.txt" from the Attachment
   End If

  fldAttach.LoadFromFile "MyFile.txt"
```

Another poster on SO asked [basically the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566610/what-is-a-programmatic-method-to-remove-attachments-on-a-access-forms-attachm). The answer includes this:

```
Private Sub DeleteCurrentAttachment()

    Dim Records     As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Attachments As DAO.Recordset2

    Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone
    Records.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark

    Set Attachments = Records!YourAttachmentFieldName.Value
    While Not Attachments.EOF
        Attachments.Delete
        Attachments.MoveNext
    Wend
    Attachments.Close

End Sub
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to apply that answer to my code. Wouldn't `Attachments.Delete` remove all the attachments, not just one?

Honestly, most of what I know about attachment controls and multi-value fields in VBA is from here in SO. From Googling, the main thing I've learned is that I ought to be using hyperlinks instead. (My client wants both options, so I have to make this work.)

Comment: Yes, the loop will delete all attachments related to parent record that has focus. Are you storing multiple attachments in each record?

Comment: Yes I am. I want to be able to delete a specific one.

Answer (score 2):

`Attachments.Delete` on the attachments subrecordset only deletes this subrecord, so not all attachments, just one.

You can check the filename in the loop, and only delete a specific one.

```
While Not Attachments.EOF
    If Attachments.FileName = "MyFile.txt"
        Attachments.Delete
    End If
    Attachments.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: In my code, `rstAttach` takes the place of `Attachments`.